# SQL INSTEAD OF Condition not evaluating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm building a team roster and trying to prevent an `INSERT` if it's determined that a given team already has too many members.  The trigger fires, but the condition doesn't evaluate.  This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RosterDeleteTrigger1
ON dbo.Roster
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @val int

        SELECT @val = COUNT(*)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT r.RosterID, r.TeamID 
            FROM Roster r
            JOIN inserted i
            ON r.RosterID = i.RosterID
            WHERE r.TeamID = i.TeamID
            AND r.PlayerStatus = 'Active'
        ) src;
        PRINT @val
        IF(@val) > 6
            PRINT 'hello'

        --More code to allow the commit if @val is under 6
    END
```

The `IF` Statement is just to test the logic right now.  So far it doesn't print `hello`.  The insert statement inserts to `TeamID 1`, which has 7 members, so it should be evaluating.  `@val` prints out a 0, so I don't know exactly what's wrong with my count query.

Ultimately I want to allow the commit if the count is low, but I haven't even figured out how to begin that.

Comment: Drop the use of a trigger. Use a IF EXISTS Statement to check the count of players and force the insert to use this method. This way you prevent the expensive insert operation (and any locks it may require)  from even occuring in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **INSTEAD OF** Trigger, so it has not inserted the records into the table yet only into the inserted pseudotable. So when you join to Roster, naturally there are no results.  I assume you want to add the results of what is currently in roster and what is in the inserted table to get your condition. In that case use a UNION statement instead of a join. Further, what happens if there is more than one team id in the insert? I would use a table variable with the count instead of the scalar variable and include the team id in it as well as the count.

Once you have determined that it is ok to add teh team members, then you write a new insert statement inserting from the inserted table to the Roster table.